# while loop not breaking, cannot find the bug

Tags: python, while-loop

Beginner here.Something is wrong with my code. While loop is not terminating. Where did I go wrong?

```
def check( x ):  # x is defaultdict(list) 
    a = sorted(x , reverse=True)
    j = 0
    while (j<len(a)):
        c = d[a[j]] # current list
        l = len(c) # current list length
        m = 0
        while (m<l) :
            if c[m] == m or c[m] == n-1-m :
                continue
            else:
                return "No"
            m = m + 1
        j = j + 1
    return "Yes"
```

Comment: Hint #1: why do you think it will terminate?

Comment: when inner loop's m reaches l and outer loop's j reaches len(a), they will stop.

Comment: You never reach  `m = m + 1`, you either continue or return

Comment: yeahhh...got it.. i have to remove `continue`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops - read here carefully about `continue` statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing this is the issue -

```
while (m<l) :
    if c[m] == m or c[m] == n-1-m :
        continue
```

Lets assume , we have a value where `c[m]` is equal to `m` . You just continue the while loop, without changing `m` (or `c` , though I am guessing `c` is not to be changed) , so the next time, it comes back to this condition , again `c[m]` is equal to `m` , since neither of them have changed, and again you do  `continue` to continue the loop. And this goes on forever.

[`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement does not execute the rest of the while loop, it continues on with the next iteration of the loop.

I think you want to increment `m` even when the condition is true? , If so try something like -

```
while (m<l) :
    if c[m] != m and c[m] != n-1-m :
        return "No"
    m = m + 1
```

I am not sure if there are any other issues in your code, since we really do not know what its supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the "continue" statement causes the infinite loop by skipping the "m = m + 1" line